# How to make a get request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, curl, parameters, request

I'm trying make a get request to get user online in a channel on my server, but i always reveive all user of my server.

I have used request module, but it not working, seem it not pass parameter "_id" on request

in curl

```
curl -s -G \
          -H "X-Auth-Token: Qv5vMPB_6aMCSv5ayQAbQCXkSsBzra_K6BbAqc7S0Fr" \
          -H "X-User-Id: 34YYb2cqqDaFz53ib" \
          -H "Accepts: application/json" \
          --data-urlencode 'query={"_id": "FC77kqfNrH39wEaKG"}' \
          http://localhost:3001/api/v1/channels.online
```

result as I expert

```
{
  "online": [
    {
      "_id": "D539dgygpWrYrNyFz",
      "username": "tranhoang"
    },
    {
      "_id": "34YYb2cqqDaFz53ib",
      "username": "mybot"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

code use request module

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'X-Auth-Token': 'Qv5vMPB_6aMCSv5ayQAbQCXkSsBzra_K6BbAqc7S0Fr',
    'X-User-Id': '34YYb2cqqDaFz53ib',
    'Accepts': 'application/json'
};

var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/channels.online',
    headers: headers,
    form: {
        query: '{"_id": "FC77kqfNrH39wEaKG"}'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        console.log(response);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

and result

```
{
  "online": [
    {
      "_id": "D539dgygpWrYrNyFz",
      "username": "tranhoang"
    },
    {
      "_id": "34YYb2cqqDaFz53ib",
      "username": "mybot"
    },
    {
      "_id": "DkiEXfaXRA5EffnHb",
      "username": "sp2"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

sp2 is not join in channel that have "_id" in form, what can i do, please help me!!

Comment: Shouldn't the `query` property be an object, not a string? That's what its docs say, anyway: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#user-content-forms

Comment: I have tried     form: { _id: "FC77kqfNrH39wEaKG" }, but nothing change !!

Answer (score 0):

To make HTTP `GET` request in Node.js using `request` module, you don't need `form` in `options` object. Instead, `qs` in `options` is the right choice.

The code would look like:

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
  'X-Auth-Token': 'Qv5v...S0Fr',
  'X-User-Id': '34YY...53ib',
  'Accepts': 'application/json'
};

var options = {
  uri: 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/channels.online',
  headers: headers,
  qs: {
    query: {"_id": "FC77kqfNrH39wEaKG"}
  },
  method: 'GET'
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
    console.log(response);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```